# Change selection / highlight color of static uitableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

How can I change the selection / highlight color of a static `UITableView`? I understand for non-static `UITableViews` I might just subclass a `UITableViewCell`, but since I can't use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with a static `UITableView` what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using static cells from storyboard, you can customize each cell **dynamically** in **`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise each cell in Interface Builder. You can set each cell's attributes by selecting it and then editing the appropriate fields in the attributes editors. For even more customised appearance/behaviour, you can even subclass a cell and let Interface Builder of its class in the identity inspector.